# 301 redirect to prevent duplicate Google Analytics when /en/ is in URL

Tags: c#, iis, episerver

We are using the latest Episerver (9) and have multiple site languages - English and Welsh. Our Google Analytics is creating Duplicate URL results because the site uses ***.com/en/testpage and ***.com/testpage. We can't use IIS rewrite Tool to create a 301 as we use Azure to host the site.
Does anyone know the best way to create a 301 redirect in c# to prevent Duplicate entries in GA?
Thanks
Jon

Comment: Have you set the language for that host name (in admin mode among the site settings)? In that case there shouldn't be any URL's prefixed with "en" for English, unless you explicitly output links to pages with the "/en/" prefix?

Comment: Azure Web Sites does support URL Rewrite just not the IIS GUI obviously. I create my rules on my local machine using hosts file to make sure rewrite behaves like I want. When modifying rewrite rules in IIS they are saved to web.config so just upload your new web.config and rewrite should work fine.

Comment: Ted, where in Episerver 8/9 do you set this up?

Answer (score 1):

You can also render a canonical link in your layout.

```
@Html.CanonicalLink()
```

Please see https://github.com/episerver/AlloyDemoKit/blob/master/src/AlloyDemoKit/Views/Shared/Layouts/_Root.cshtml